# AngularJS Directive scope binding issue in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

am having a directive which is a stopwatch. It is placed under ng-repeat so the user can create as many stopwatches he needs. All these stopwatch has their own play/pause and stop button. 
The issue am facing is when the user starts the first stopwatch all the other watches starts running, but when starting from the last watch it works fine. What am I doing wrong here.[Find the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H95QpVbEhPCkQYBQQpuY?p=preview)

my link function: Complete working code is in plunker

```
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

  var start_button = angular.element(document.querySelector('.play'));
  var pause_button = angular.element(document.querySelector('.pause'));
  var stop_button = angular.element(document.querySelector('.stop'));

  start_button.on('click', ctrl.start);
  pause_button.on('click', ctrl.pause);
  stop_button.on('click', ctrl.stop);
  scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    start_button.off('click', ctrl.start);
    pause_button.off('click', ctrl.pause);
    stop_button.off('click', ctrl.stop);
  });

},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that in your directive template you have an ng-click so this code can be removed

```
 var start_button = angular.element(document.querySelector('.play'));
  var pause_button = angular.element(document.querySelector('.pause'));
  var stop_button = angular.element(document.querySelector('.stop'));

  start_button.on('click', ctrl.start);
  pause_button.on('click', ctrl.pause);
  stop_button.on('click', ctrl.stop);
  scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    start_button.off('click', ctrl.start);
    pause_button.off('click', ctrl.pause);
    stop_button.off('click', ctrl.stop);
  });
```

and then it works :)

[working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oZl7F3h9DGUWG5nSjyON?p=preview)